# Joining tables based on sequence of events/timestamps

Tags: sql

I hope I can explain properly. For a quick example context, let's say the Login and Create Page tables below, store user made events - with a given UserID, Timestamp, and extra info (ABC and XYZ).

I want to join both tables together on UserID, but only keep the entries where the Create Page timestamp is   after the Login timestamp, but only the first occurrence closest to the Login timestamp - essentially match where the timestamps are the closest, but Login before Create Page. The time difference also can't be longer than 10 hours. An example of data is below

- **Login**

```
   UserID | Timestamp           | ABC 
   1      | 2022-12-15 07:05:00 | aa 
   1      | 2022-12-15 07:10:00 | ab 
   2      | 2022-12-14 05:55:55 | ac 
   1      | 2022-12-11 17:00:00 | ad 
   3      | 2022-12-11 05:00:00 | ae 
   2      | 2022-12-10 05:06:00 | af 
   2      | 2022-12-10 08:00:00 | ag
```

- **Create Page**

```
   UserID | Timestamp           | XYZ 
   1      | 2022-12-10 02:22:22 | xa 
   2      | 2022-12-10 08:10:00 | xb 
   2      | 2022-12-10 05:15:00 | xc 
   2      | 2022-12-10 05:20:00 | xd 
   1      | 2022-12-11 17:10:00 | xe 
   1      | 2022-12-11 18:00:00 | xf 
   3      | 2022-12-12 15:00:00 | xg 
   1      | 2022-12-15 07:15:00 | xh
```

- **Expected Result**

```
   UserID | XYZ | ABC 
   2      | xb  | ag 
   2      | xc  | af 
   1      | xe  | ad 
   1      | ab  | xh
```

I hope it made sense. Anyone able to help?

I'm an SQL novice, and all my tries just failed miserably. I have no idea where to start to approach this and haven't found anything here yet that helped me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think I have what you need:

```
SELECT 
    e1.UserID 
    , e1.Timestamp as Login
    , e2.Timestamp as Create_Page

          FROM Login_table e1
          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
              UserID 
              , Timestamp
            FROM Create_page_table
          ) e2 ON e1.UserID = e2.UserID 
               AND e1.Timestamp <= e2.Timestamp  
               AND DATE_DIFF(e2.Timestamp , e1.Timestamp , MINUTE) <= 600
          
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e1.UserID , e1.Timestamp ORDER BY DATE_DIFF(e2.Timestamp , e1.Timestamp , MINUTE)) = 1
ORDER BY UserId, Login
```

Clarification: QUALIFY is available on Bigquery. (This query was created with for that platform in mind).

The QUALIFY at the bottom will only keep the events that are closest to each other (in time difference). It is similar to adding that window function into the SELECT and later on filtering by the one that equals 1.

Comment: You really only need to order by the second date rather than the whole date difference expression. That might benefit index usage?

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
l.UserID,
l.LoginTime 'LoginTime',
cp.CreationTime 'First Page Creation Time Within 10 Hours',
CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, l.LoginTime, cp.CreationTime) AS FLOAT) / 60 'Page Created After Login in Hours'
FROM @Logins l
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT TOP 1 *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY CreationTime) AS RowNum FROM @CreatePages) cp ON cp.UserID = l.UserID 
    AND cp.CreationTime > l.LoginTime 
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, l.LoginTime, cp.CreationTime) <= 10
ORDER BY LoginTime
```

If you want to see rows for when a user logged in but didn't create a page within 10 hours, then replace the WHERE clause with the same but added as a condition to the JOIN. Because the JOIN is a LEFT OUTER JOIN, you will see all Logins but will, in the case of no page creations within 10 hours, NULLs for the PageCreation time and the hours after login.

Comment: Conceptually, it seems to be close to what I want but it doesn't work.

The top 1 is limiting all the partitioned groups by one entry only, and thus would only match one single row from your CP - if it actually meets the match criteria (UserIDs and the CreationTime being superior to the LoginTime).

So yes, I would only want to match the first entry in that particular partition that matches the criteria - but SELECT TOP 1 is making it only have 1 entry, ever.

Comment: Obviously, without the top 1, it would match all entries with the same UserID and CreationTime > LoginTime - however I only want it to match with the first valid one (and earliest CreationTime)

Comment: Your derived table is only going to be "evaluated" once. So unfortunately this won't quite work the way you intended.